# how does angular implement bind-once directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've looked through source code but haven't found relative piece of code. I'm particularly interested in bind-once watchers and the way to attach them. At the moment I've done the following:

```
var removeNodeTypeWatcher = scope.$watch(function () {
    return paneController.getNodeType();
}, function (value) {
    if (value) {
        scope.nodeType = value;
        // as soon as the value is defined we no longer need watcher
        removeNodeTypeWatcher();
    }
});
```

Comment: is getNodeType asynchronous? Otherwise, do you even need a watch?

Comment: good point, but the question is not about that :) let's assume that it is

Comment: `bindonce`does the same, unregister watch when value is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the specific expression

> ::

like so:

```
<div>{{::item}}</div>
```

or

```
<ul>  
   <li ng-repeat="item in ::items">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

to bind expression once since angular 1.3: [bind once since 1.3](http://swirlycheetah.com/native-bind-once-in-angularjs-1-3/)

Also, there are specific libraries like:

[**angular-once**](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once) or [**bindonce**](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)

**EDIT:**

I found the following function in the source of angularjs 1.3:

```
function oneTimeWatch(scope, listener, objectEquality, deregisterNotifier, parsedExpression) {
    var unwatch, lastValue;
    return unwatch = scope.$watch(function oneTimeWatch(scope) {
        return parsedExpression(scope);
    }, function oneTimeListener(value, old, scope) {
        lastValue = value;
        if (isFunction(listener)) {
            listener.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        if (isDefined(value)) {
            scope.$$postDigest(function() {
                if (isDefined(lastValue)) {
                    unwatch();
                }
            });
        }
    }, objectEquality, deregisterNotifier);
}
```

It is located at `src/ng/parse.js`, starting at line 1031:[oneTimeWatch](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/86d55c1ded21a5be6091344493d70c6dc4194e43#diff-fa3a9c02d707ed4ce850dcf11808a205)

However, in 1.4, the function is called

> oneTimeWatchDelegate

Comment: And if you look at the source of `bindonce` you can see they use the same approach as Maximus

Comment: @Manube, thanks, but I was asking about how this is implemented inside angular.

Comment: @DieterGoetelen, can you point me to the source code line with bind once?

Comment: @Maximus awch, I was pointing to `angular-once`, source: https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once/blob/master/once.js#L22

Comment: oops, sorry, had misinterpreted. Indeed the relative code seems well hidden, will keep looking...

Comment: @DieterGoetelen, I see, ok. My question is about native angular's implementation, since they already have it from 1.3

Comment: edited my answer, found oneTimeWatch function in ng/parse.js of angular1.3, hoping that's what you were looking for

Comment: @Manube, thanks! Yeah, that's what I was looking for. Seems that it's not much different from my own implementation.